# GARCH models testing in R

Tags: r, model, statistics, finance, arima

I would to take five parametrs: a, b, c, d and mean of standards deviation from every model (it is a normal value, no matrix) and store this information as a vector, then using rbind to crate matrix which I can search for the models and parameters.

I was trying with nested loops like:

```
for (a in 0:2){
  for (b in 0:2){
    for (c in 1:2){
      for (d in 1:2){
  Garch_model  <- garchFit(~arma(a,b)+garch(c,d), include.mean = TRUE,cond.dist = c("norm"),data = dax_data)
  ValidationBox <- rbind(ValidationBox,c(a,b,c,d,mean(Garch_model@sigma.t))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Error: unexpected '}' in: "  ValidationBox <-
>   rbind(ValidationBox,c(a,b,c,d,mean(Garch_model@sigma.t))
>        }"
>       } Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>     } Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   } Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Can anyone tell me what's the issue?

Comment: Try adding `ValidationBox <- data.frame()` before your code. Also it looks like there's a `)` missing. It should be: `rbind(ValidationBox,c(a,b,c,d,mean(Garch_model@sigma.t)))`

Comment: Thanks, but i still recive an error Formula and data units do not match :(

Comment: It appears that the `formula` doesn't like previously declared variables... a quick search gave [a way you could fix this](http://grokbase.com/p/r/r-help/108g0gf2yq/r-fgarch-how-to-use-garchfit-in-loop). You could try to work out something based on that answer. I could give you a hand earliest by sunday, as I'm currently busy.

Comment: Thanks!! i will try it in free and hopefully come back with positive info. :)